# Set PythonHome to /home/appuser/Env/myproject django - uwsgi ImportError: No module named site

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I am using uwsgi and nginx for deployment of django project, i am new to this server side configuration and i m using this article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04 .
After executing below command

`uwsgi --http <my_server_ip>:8080 --home /home/appuser/Env/myproject --chdir /home/appuser/myproject -w myproject.wsgi`

i am getting this error : **Set PythonHome to /home/appuser/Env/myproject
ImportError: No module named site**
There are many similar questions on SO, but i did not find any solutions

Comment: Please don't ask us to read a tutorial to answer your question. Post the relevent sections here